# call windows system command through fortran without showing the shell window and output the result to an external file

Tags: windows, file-io, fortran, intel-fortran

I'm doing a little project using Fortran. A part of the code is designed to check the PC's mac address. Currently, I'm using call system command as follows:

`CALL SYSTEM("ipconfig -all >result.tmp")` 
Above code will invoke the windows ipconfig-all command and output the information to an external file result.tmp. Later this file will be read to check the mac address.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-fo...

I tried that solution, it works fine for the system command "ipconfig -all", but I did not figure out how to output the result to an external file.  Does anyone can give me some hints on how to achieve that ?

Above works, except one annoying thing. The Fortran code will be compiled as a DLL and used by another C# program. The annoying thing is, whenever above code is executed in the C# program, a console window will be prompted shortly and then closed. I searched the forum to find if there is some way to disable the window prompt, it turns out there is some solution in the following link:

Comment: Your link is wrong. The *following link* at the and is missing altogether. What happens when you do your `CALL SYSTEM("ipconfig -all >result.tmp")`? Is the result file not created? What exactly happens instead?

Comment: SYSTEM doesn't invoke a shell and thus redirection won't work. I tried ShellExecute, but couldn't get redirection to work there either. In general I would recommend instead using Windows API routines to retrieve the MAC address programatically rather than trying to parse the output of ipconfig (which may change or may have multiple adapters.)  The GetAdaptersAddresses function will do this, but you'll have to write your own interface as Intel doesn't include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also posted this at the [Intel forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/802103) and user Paul Curtis replied with an example of how to get the MAC address directly using the Windows API.

Since StackOverflow prefers answers that aren't just links, I've included the code below.

```
MODULE MAC  
    USE ifwinty  
    USE charfunc
    IMPLICIT NONE 
    PUBLIC GetMacInfo       !, PortExists
    PRIVATE
    SAVE

    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: MAX_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH = 128  
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: MAX_ADAPTER_NAME_LENGTH        = 256  
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: MAX_ADAPTER_ADDRESS_LENGTH     =   8  
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: MIB_IF_TYPE_ETHERNET           =   6  ! Ipifcons.h

    TYPE IP_ADDRESS_STRING  
        CHARACTER(LEN=16) :: String  
    END TYPE IP_ADDRESS_STRING

    TYPE IP_MASK_STRING  
        CHARACTER(LEN=16) :: String  
    END TYPE IP_MASK_STRING

    TYPE t_IP_ADDR_STRING   
        INTEGER (LPLONG)         :: pNext  
        TYPE (IP_ADDRESS_STRING) :: IpAddress  
        TYPE (IP_MASK_STRING)    :: IpMask  
        INTEGER (DWORD)          :: Context  
    END TYPE t_IP_ADDR_STRING

    TYPE t_IP_ADAPTER_INFO  
        INTEGER(LPLONG)         :: pNext   
        INTEGER(DWORD)          :: ComboIndex  
        CHARACTER(LEN=MAX_ADAPTER_NAME_LENGTH+4)        :: AdapterName  
        CHARACTER(LEN=MAX_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH+4) :: Description  
        INTEGER(UINT)           :: AddressLength  
        INTEGER(BYTE)           :: Address(MAX_ADAPTER_ADDRESS_LENGTH)  
        INTEGER(DWORD)          :: Index  
        INTEGER(ULONG)          :: iType  
        INTEGER(ULONG)          :: DhcpEnabled  
        INTEGER(LPLONG)         :: pCurrentIpAddress   
        TYPE(t_IP_ADDR_STRING)  :: IpAddressList  
        TYPE(t_IP_ADDR_STRING)  :: GatewayList  
        TYPE(t_IP_ADDR_STRING)  :: DhcpServer  
        INTEGER(BOOL)           :: HaveWins  
        TYPE(t_IP_ADDR_STRING)  :: PrimaryWinsServer  
        TYPE(t_IP_ADDR_STRING)  :: SecondaryWinsServer  
        INTEGER(ULONG)          :: LeaseObtained  
        INTEGER(ULONG)          :: LeaseExpires  
    END TYPE t_IP_ADAPTER_INFO

    !   must link with IpHlpApi.lib to access this API function;
    !   this interface is not included in ifwinty
    INTERFACE  
        INTEGER(BOOL) FUNCTION GetAdaptersInfo (arg1, arg2)  
            USE ifwinty  
            !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DEFAULT, STDCALL, DECORATE, ALIAS:'GetAdaptersInfo' :: GetAdaptersInfo  
            INTEGER(LPLONG) :: arg1  
            INTEGER(LPLONG) :: arg2  
        END FUNCTION  
    END INTERFACE

CONTAINS  


    SUBROUTINE GetMacInfo (hwnd, id)
        USE contwrap
        IMPLICIT NONE

        !   dialog window handle and set of static-text IDs for display
        INTEGER(HANDLE), INTENT(IN)         :: hwnd
        INTEGER, INTENT(IN), DIMENSION(4)   :: id 

        CHARACTER(LEN=200)                  :: msg
        INTEGER                             :: i, nc, count
        INTEGER, PARAMETER                  :: acount = 16
        TYPE(t_IP_ADAPTER_INFO),ALLOCATABLE :: ai(:)  

        count = 0

        !   allow for multiple adapters
        ALLOCATE (ai(acount))
        nc = SIZEOF(ai)
        IF (GetAdaptersInfo(LOC(ai), LOC(nc)) == 0) THEN  

            DO i = 1, acount
                SELECT CASE (ai(i)%iType)
                CASE (MIB_IF_TYPE_ETHERNET)

                    !   line 1: description and MAC address
                    !nc = INDEX(ai(i)%Description, CHAR(0)) - 1
                    !WRITE (msg, '(A,",  ",5(Z2.2,"-"),Z2.2)') &
                    !    ai(i)%Description(1:nc),              &
                    !    ai(i)%Address(1:ai(i)%AddressLength)
                    nc = INDEX(ai(i)%Description, CHAR(0))
                    msg = ai(i)%Description(1:nc)
                    count = count + 1
                    CALL StaticSetText (hwnd, id(count), msg)
                    CALL ControlSetVisible (hwnd, id(count), .TRUE.)

                    !   line 2: IP and Gateway addresses
                    WRITE (msg, '("IP Addr: ",A,"  Gateway: ",A)')  &
                        ai(i)%IpAddressList%IpAddress%string,       &
                        ai(i)%GatewayList%IpAddress%string
                    CALL remove_nulls (msg)
                    count = count + 1
                    CALL StaticSetText (hwnd, id(count), msg)
                    CALL ControlSetVisible (hwnd, id(count), .TRUE.)

                    IF (count >= 4) EXIT
                END SELECT
                IF (ai(i)%pNext == NULL) EXIT  
            END DO

        END IF
        DEALLOCATE (ai)

    END SUBROUTINE GetMacInfo

END MODULE MAC
```

Comment: Truly appreciate for your help  Doctor Fortran. And also Paul's help.  I will try above codes to see if it works.

Comment: There is a much easier way if 1) You still want to parse ipconfig output, 2) You have Intel Fortran 16 or later: `call execute_command_line ('ipconfig -all > ipx.txt')`

Comment: Is Intel Fortran 16 completely backward compatible with IVF 2013? If so I may consider to change to Fortran 16 instead